# object.__init__() takes exactly one argument error when trying import Forecaster

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting this error

```
object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

when I am trying to run this in Jupyter notebook:

`from greykite.framework.templates.forecaster import Forecaster`

I am expecting Forecaster will get imported smoothly

Comment: Dear Tina, warm welcome to SO. Please use correct upper case letters to make it easier to read your question. Also try code formatting and quotation. Also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . In the current state it is impossible to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same problem, but in Google Colab.

Apparently, there's a problem with a recent Holidays update. Before you run your above code, you should do the following:

```
!pip install holidays==0.24.0
```

And it should fix your issue (or at least, it worked for me)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Use these steps to fix it.

1. Uninstall the greykite library if you have it installed
2. Install all the libraries from the [requirement.txt](https://github.com/linkedin/greykite/blob/master/requirements-dev.txt) file using the the command `!pip install -r <path_to_requirement_txt>`
3. Reinstall greykite and that will fix it

I made a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rHzwaONkqUk) about how to fix it too.